# How to access the mailmerge recipient variable?

Tags: vba, excel, ms-word, mailmerge

I need to access this value, is it possible? Where is it stored. I need to access it through VBA (it's used in a script).

Here is a picture of the number I want to access.

[image]

Comment: How and where is the recipient number number stored within the Word doc?

Comment: Thats what I want to know... I solved the deletion problem, divided the template into sections and from there it was very easy. But yeah @destination-data That is my only question as of now.

Comment: And how to make the commandbutton invisible in the printed version of the tempate of course, have I done it right?

Comment: We cannot see the word document.  Unless you can describe the structure we cannot tell you how to access the number (the answer depends on exactly how/where it's been entered).

Comment: Also you don't need a button, you can use short key to run your macro ex: ctrl+j or whatever letter you want.

Comment: @destination-data The "recipient number / Variable" is not in the template itself, it is the number of the recipient, for example, if I choose to preview the result, and click the "next" button There is a small number going up and down depending on if I pressed next or previous

Comment: @destination-data [link]https://stevechasedocs.files.wordpress.com/2014/08/preview-results.png?w=640

Comment: @Ionut Thanks for the answer but the buttons are no longer a problem

Comment: When you edit questions please don't remove large chunks.  It makes the comments very hard to follow, for those that did not see the original version.  Take @Lonut's comment as an example.  Through no fault of his/her own, this comment no longer makes sense.

Comment: @destination-data Thank you, I'll be sure to keep that in mind next time, have a good day sir.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want the [ActiveRecord property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/VBA/Word-VBA/articles/mailmergedatasource-activerecord-property-word) of the [MailMergeDataSource object](https://msdn.microsoft.com/VBA/Word-VBA/articles/mailmergedatasource-object-word).

Example:

```
' Displays currently active record.
Msgbox ThisDocument.MailMerge.DataSource.ActiveRecord
```